# Can I have index created on temp tables (#temp) which are created dynamically in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, nested, temp-tables

I am creating temp tables (`#temp_table`) in my stored procedure. It is a huge table with large data. Then I am creating a index in the storeed procedure as it is required for faster query to the temp table. But when I execute the stored procedure, the index is not used. The index is not being created when the stored procedure is executed.

## Pseudo code

```
CREATE PROC abcdefg
AS
...
SELECT col_a, col_b, col_c....    
  INTO #temp_table
  FROM .....
  WHERE ....
...
CREATE INDEX abc_idx ON #temp_table (col_a)
...
SELECT col_a FROM #temp_table WITH (INDEX (abc_idx))
...
GO
```

When I try to execute the stored proc, it is not recognizing the index. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 5):

This usually happens because the access plans for the temp tables have been generated before the indexes ever existed.

Fortunately, you can use table-level constraints to get around this problem. Since the indexes to support UNIQUE and PRIMARY KEY constraints are defined at the same time as the temp table, the optimizer will always be able to use these indexes.

Reference: [Optimizing Performance / Indexes on Temp Tables](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/optimizing-performance-indexes-on-temp-tables)

Comment: Thanks OMG. Your suggestion was useful.

Comment: @Ponies - the article you referenced is from 2004, but is it safe to assume the advice in there regarding #temp tables is still "best practice"?

Answer (score 2):

I tried the code you suggested using Sql Server 2005

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Test
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #Test (
            ID INT,
            Code VARCHAR(20)
    )
    CREATE INDEX test_ind ON #Test (Code)

    INSERT INTO #Test (ID,Code) SELECT ID, Code FROM MyTable

    SELECT Code
    FROM    #Test WITH(INDEX(test_ind))

    DROP TABLE #Test
END
```

When running the

```
EXEC Test
```

Command with Include Actual Execution Plan, it does show that the index was used.

Comment: Thanks Astander for your quick response. I tested your solution and it is working fine. The difference seems to be with the way stored procs execute "SELECT INTO #temp" and "CREATE TABLE #temp" queries. Another less preferable solution is to create the stored proc with "with recompile" option. That again worked.

Once again thanks for your help.